# Marginal Density of X

Tags: statistics, integration

I need to find the marginal density of $x$ where

$$f(x, y) = xe^{-x-y}$$
Where the inputs must abide by: $x, y > 0$

My approach to solving the problem was:

$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty xe^{-x-y}dxdy$

$= \int_0^\infty \left[ (x+1)(-e^{-x-y})\right]_0^\infty dy$

$= \int_0^\infty 0 dy$

$= 0$

But that does not make sense at all. The density function should not and cannot be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your error:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x e^{-x-y}dx} & = (x+1)(-e^{-x-y}) \bigg|_{0}^{\infty} \\
 & = \frac{x+1}{e^{x+y}} \bigg|_{\infty}^{0} \\
 & = e^{-y}
\end{align}$$

And then

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}{xe^{-x-y} dx dy} = 1$$

Comment: Ah, that looks a lot better. Is $e^{-y}$ the marginal density for $x$?

Comment: Ok, well thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

when you get to $$\int_0^\infty (L +1)(\frac{-1}{e^L+e^y})dy=\int_0^\infty e^{-y}dy=\lim_{L\to \infty} -1[e^{-L} - e^0] = -1\cdot-1= 1$$

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy. Everytime you have a joint density function (x,y), if you need to get the marginal density of x, just integrate the joint density function respect to y in its current interval.

Therefore, the marginal density of x is f(x) = Exp[-x]*x.

( Integrate[f[x, y], {y, 0, Infinity}] ;; Integrate[%, {x, 0, Infinity}] )

Comment: So, $marginal density = e^{-x}x$? and the line below that is: $\int_0^\infty f(x, y) dy$? But what was the last part after the `;;`?